# How to integrate debitcard payment gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, payment-gateway

I am new learner for ruby on rails3 and I want to integrate payment gatway for debitcard (Price should be in RS (india rupees)).

please suggest me any payment gayway for debitcard and how to integrate it with my app.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a big and complex subject area, not at all easy to answer. It's too much for a single SO question. Recommendations for which tools to use for your project are also off-topic.

Comment: I can use any tools for integrate it(It may be active merchant)

Comment: ActiveMerchant has a long list of supported gateways here: http://rdoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/master/frames - I don't know which of these will be best for INR. I suggest you take a look. Many gateways (e.g. Paypal) will have a developer portal where you can try out code without making real transactions.

Comment: A nice place to start would be from cody fauser's peepcode book on active merchant. It talks about the best practices and also a dummy app which u can try out before beginning on the actual app. After that decide on the payment gateway. IMHO, Braintree is a nice one and supported by active merchant too. However, there are many other good options available too.